# jquery select inputs that do not have a parent with a particular class

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I select all inputs that do not have an parent of a particular class?

Here I just want to get the inputs that do not have a parent with the class `not-parent`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:text').css('color', '#FF1200'); 
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MFtv3/

I have tried `filter()` without success. :/

Thanks!

Comment: what are the parents? are they all divs?

Comment: @tpaksu Hi. Yeah everything has a div parent. But there's one div that has a particular class that I don't want to select any of its `input:text` children. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

if your inputs are all contained with div's;

if you want top level to bottom level parent check:

```
$("div:not(.not-parent) input").css('color', '#FF1200');
```

or if you want only one level parent check:

```
$("div:not(.not-parent) > input").css('color', '#FF1200');
```

Edit: if it has ancestors of the same type without the class use this:

```
$('input').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).parents('div').hasClass('not-parent');
}).css('color', '#FF1200');
```

Comment: that selector isn't specific enough - it'll check grandparents too

Comment: You only want one level checking then?

Comment: Although the question doesn't really say but seems like `$("div.parent input").css('color', '#FF1200');` is just the easiest solution...

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS Yes, you're right. Though I didn't specify, this is totally all right that it checks grandparents. The parent I'm checking for the existence of is actually three levels up. Thanks!

Comment: @thomas you should have specified _ancestor_ then, not _parent_.  The difference matters!

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS yea I didn't see the fiddle over there. You're right.

Comment: @tpaksu How can I amend it so that it works for ancestors..? http://jsfiddle.net/MFtv3/2/ Thanks

Comment: @thomas also since input itself is kind of vague, and it looks like you wanted textboxes use `input[type="text"]` as it uses css selectors (and will be quicker) than the deprecated `:text`

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS good point. But it still doesn't work for ancestors. Any ideas there?